# Language resolution strategy inconsistency with official docs

Tags: android, localization

According to [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support), on Android prior to 7.0 if application can't find exact combination of device's Country&Region, it will use default language.

I'm using Android 6.0 (Genymotion).
In application I have localization for next languages:

```
strings.xml - English - default<br>
de-rAT<br>
de-rCH<br>
de-rDE
```

On device I choose `de-rLI` and I expect to see my app in English, as my app has no such alternative resource.
But! My app is running under `de-rDE` translation.

Why is that happening?

Comment: I guess that German (Germany), `de-rDE` is closer to German (Liecthenstein) much more than `en` or `default`.

Comment: I provided a link to official docs, which states another.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Jump to the `improvements` section and dive into the (new) `values-b+xy+jkl` format.

Comment: Yeap, but improvements were introduced in Android 7+. And I'm talking about Android 6.

Comment: Then you're going to use the *support library*, I guess.

Comment: That's system behavior, how can it be changed by using support library?

Comment: The support library, as usual, brings the missing features to the lower OS versiors. That's what it's meant to.

Comment: Ah, that's possible thing. Thank you!